# Transform key points in image

Tags: vb.net, math, matrix, system.drawing

[image]

I would like to transform several key points of an image.

As one can see in the example image, only parts of the image are transformed while other parts of the image are left intact. This way only the nose gets thinner.

As far as I know, a Matrix can only transform an entire image, but that is not what I need.

Is there a function in System.Drawing that would allow me to do this easily?

Comment: There are two straight-forward approaches: 1. Represent the transform as a displacement vector field. 2. Represent the transform as a sampling at various locations (e.g. a 4x4 grid of transforms) and blend the transforms in between. Both approaches would require to optimize for the representation given the limited input that you have. Both require some kind of regularization (e.g. the transform should be close to the identity).

Comment: @NicoSchertler Thank you. Can you explain "transform should be close to the identity"? Do you mean that that shifting the upper right-top "nose point" should affect the region left and bottom, but not so much to the top and the right?

Comment: What I mean is that if you don't have a point near a region, you probably want to preserve the region.